# UIScrollView next previous button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

next button is only working for 2 images i have 10 images in array after two images it does not move forward previous button is working for all images but next button only work up to one and second image
       Below are the next Button Code

```
       - (IBAction)  nextButtonAction {

    if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x <= self.scrollView.frame.size.width ) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x +self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
     frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
     [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
       }

     }


 // Here is the previous button code


      -(IBAction)previousButtonAction
    {


    if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x >= self.scrollView.frame.size.width ) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x -self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
   } 
   }
```

Adding images to the data base

```
     -(IBAction)addToCollectionButtonAction{




      GeoNewsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (GeoNewsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication   sharedApplication] delegate];

   // Create a Coffee Object.
    Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];

    int pageNumber  = [pageControl currentPage]; 
   NSLog(collectionImage);


   RowTwo*aRowTwo=[appDelegate.articles objectAtIndex:pageNumber];




    NSString*thumb2=aRowTwo.image;

    coffeeObj.thumb = thumb2;
   coffeeObj.path = thumb2; 





         [appDelegate addCoffee:coffeeObj];



      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `self.scrollView.frame.size.width`  With `self.scrollView.contentSize.width`

```
    - (IBAction)  nextButtonAction {

    if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x <= self.scrollView.contentSize.width ) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x +self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
     frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
     [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
       }

     }


 // Here is the previous button code


      -(IBAction)previousButtonAction
    {


    if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x >= self.scrollView.frame.size.width ) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x -self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
   } 
   }
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me another thing i want to ask that if i save this image in data base it saves only the image which is at index one only i can post the code above

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)  nextButtonAction {

    if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x < (self.scrollView.frame.size.width*10) ) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x +self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
        pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
    }

}
```